# tried to include swagger in my spring boot app but I am getting this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, documentation, swagger-ui

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.example.mongo.NewMongoDemoApplication.main(NewMongoDemoApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89) ~[springfox-spi-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

the error I am getting

Tried @EnableSwagger2 annotation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On your swagger  configuration add @EnableWebMVC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).